# Disable fn-key toggling the touchbar

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra, touch-bar

I want to disable the toggling of the touch bar while pressing the fn-key. It should stay at "App Controls with Control Strip" by default. I am accessing the function-keys with a modifier + numbers row, means I don't need the fn-key to access the function-keys on the touch bar. This way I can create some other handy shortcuts with fn. But I don't like that every time I press it, the touch bar thinks it needs to switch to a different view.

If there is no system settings for this I am happy with a script or anything else that can solve this. Thanks in advance!